# I can't figure out how to handle user input as strings

Tags: python, string, input, sys

I'm really new to Python so I don't know much of the syntax. I'm trying to write a program that accepts words in separate lines and adds each word to an array. I tried using isalpha() to break the loop after all the words were inputted. But the loop would break even if it was a word. Please help! Edit: I'd also like to know how to get rid of the \n in the output.

```
import sys; args = sys.argv[1:]
import fileinput
words = []
for line in fileinput.input():
   if line.isalpha() == False:
    fileinput.close()
   words.append(line)
print (words)
```

Input: hello

Output: ['hello\n']

Comment: What input do you want to use to terminate the loop?

Comment: Pretty much anything that's not a word, so isalpha() should work.

Comment: [isalpha](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha): Return True if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character, False otherwise. You might need to add `line = line.rstrip()` before the `if` statement.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! I'll try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation for isalpha](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

> Return True if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character, False otherwise.

A little work in IPython:

```py
In [1]: 'hello\n'.isalpha()
Out[1]: False

In [2]: 'hello\n'.rstrip().isalpha()
Out[2]: True
```

I would fix the immediate problem with something like this:

```py
for line in fileinput.input():
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.isalpha() == False:
        fileinput.close()
    words.append(line)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If you don't mind me asking, why does it automatically say \n?

Comment: ```\n``` This is the end of the line

Comment: @JuminHan The `\n` comes from [the POSIX standard definition of a line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206)